# Populating Dynamic React Router URL Path Params in a TypeScript-friendly Way

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-router

In the past when setting up React Router I've used functions to generate dynamic URL paths. As an example, if I had a path like `/some/:id/path` I'd use:

```js
const paths = {
  somePath: (id = ':id') => `/some/${id}/path`,
};
```

This allows for setting up a Route as `<Route path={paths.somePath()} />` (`/some/:id/path`) and works well for navigation like `<Link to={paths.somePath('1234')} />` (`/some/1234/path`).

I'm now working on a TypeScript project which stores paths as static Enum values:

```js
enum Path {
  SOME_PATH: '/some/:id/path'
}
```

This works great for the Route component as `'/some/:id/path'` is exactly what I need, but for navigating I need to replace that `:id` with the correct value.

At first I mimicked my original `paths` object by spreading the `Path` enum into it and overriding the `SOME_PATH` key, but this felt like an unnecessary complication and meant I was breaking case convention by using all-caps for a generic object key:

```
const paths = {
  ...Paths,
  SOME_PATH: (id = ':id') => Paths.SOME_PATH.replace(':id', id)
}
```

Now I'm just directly calling `SOME_PATH.replace` wherever navigation occurs, but this feels dirty especially when similar navigation occurs in multiple places:

```
<Link to={Path.SOME_PATH.replace(':id', 1234) />
```

I know that for state values React Router allows for something like:

```js
history.push(Path.SOME_PATH, { id: '1234' })
```

This however doesn't change the path itself, so it ultimately navigates to `'/some/:id/path'` exactly whilst providing access to the `1234` value separately.

Does React Router have any built-in way of populating path parameters like these?

Comment: I believe [generatePath](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/generatePath) is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using react-router v6 you can use useParams hook to fetch params info like this.

```
import React from 'react';
import {useParams} from 'react-router-dom';

const AccountDetailView: React.FC = (): JSX.Element => {
  const params = useParams();
  return <>{`View Account ID "${params.id}"`}</>;
};

export default AccountDetailView;
```

for more info you can refer following link https://typescript.tv/react/upgrade-to-react-router-v6/